# Click top button from 2 buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, click, applescript

I am currently working my automator and it has a limit to operate I think this method is the solution,

I'm having trouble on how to click this link, if anyone can help me create AppleScript using safari app. that would be help me save a lot of time. 
If you can help combine applescript and jQuery or javascript for this to click

Here is the target link to click

```
<a href="/admin/products/3424746569792/variants/27652747591744" class="ui-button ui-button--size-small" data-bind-event-click="saveScrollPosition(this)" data-track-click="{ action: 'Edit variant', category: 'Products' }">Edit</a>
```

bunch of them HTML:

```
<td class="new-variants-table__cell">
              <div class="next-field__connected-wrapper next-field__connected-wrapper--align-right">
                <a href="/admin/products/3424746569792/variants/27652747591744" class="ui-button ui-button--size-small" data-bind-event-click="saveScrollPosition(this)" data-track-click="{ action: 'Edit variant', category: 'Products' }">Edit</a>
                <button class="ui-button ui-button--size-small" data-bind-event-click="deleteVariantModal_27652747591744.show()" data-track-click="{ action: 'Delete variant', category: 'Products' }" type="button" name="button"><svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="next-icon next-icon--size-20"> <use xlink:href="#delete-minor"></use> </svg></button>

              </div>
              <script data-define="{deleteVariantModal_27652747591744: new Shopify.Modal(this)}" type="text/html" class="modal_source"><header><h2>Delete Chrome?</h2><button type="button" name="button" class="btn--link close-modal">Close</button></header>

<form class="edit_product_variant" id="edit_product_variant_27652747591744" autocomplete="off" data-define="{ deleteForm: new Shopify.Form(this) }" data-tg-refresh-on-success="modal variant-row-27652747591744" data-tg-remote="true" action="/admin/products/3424746569792/variants/27652747591744" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="vHjz4tkmojd0dpVMZeZsQt3Bn/EaumOoZrNxR1awHaHaQnNQSsO1YxJglzNwoNthWoBwIlCjlxVPwmiLpTc5UA==" />
  <div class="body">
    <p>
      Are you sure you want to delete the variant <strong>Chrome</strong>? This action cannot be reversed.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="ui-button close-modal" type="button" name="button">Cancel</button>
    <button class="ui-button js-btn-loadable btn-destroy-no-hover" type="submit" name="button">Delete</button>
  </div>
</form></script>
            </td>
```

Comment: Have you tried e.g.: `tell application "Safari" to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('ui-button ui-button--size-small')[0].click();" in document 1`

Comment: Wow perfectly working, It has 2 buttons I change the 0 to 1 in your code. Thank you so much.

Comment: If their are several buttons on the page with the same class name `ui-button ui-button--size-small` ... `[0]` Would be the first button, `[1]` Would be the second button, `[2]` Would be the third button, etc.